# ObjectContext context creation logging in Entity Framework 4

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I'm having a problem where an application (a Web API project) is significantly slower in its production environment than others in which we've tested it before deployment.

So I thought about adding some logging to my EF context just to see if creating the context (and its connection) was the problem.

I'm trying, from a single place, to do all this logging as I don't want to add bits of code everywhere in all controller methods.

I can use the partial `OnContextCreated` method to log an entry once the creation process is done, like such:

In the designer file:

```
public partial class CustomerPortalEntities : ObjectContext
{
    //...
    partial void OnContextCreated();
}
```

and in another physical file:

```
public partial class CustomerPortalEntities : ObjectContext
{
    partial void OnContextCreated()
    {
        string message = string.Format("Created database context at {0}", DateTime.Now.ToString());
        EventLogger.WriteEntry(message, null, System.Diagnostics.EventLogEntryType.Information);
    }
}
```

But how would I log an entry right before this when anywhere in my project, the following is executed ?

```
using (CustomerPortalEntities ctx = new CustomerPortalEntities())
{
    //...
}
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: You can't do it before, the first line of the constructor is the first opportunity you are going to get to log anything.

Comment: @BenRobinson So there's no way to do it without having to modify the designer file (which gets rebuilt if I refresh the model), right ?

Comment: It depends on how your context is generated, if you are using t4 templates then you can modify the templates so that the generated context contains your custom code. Before you start down this road though i would think carefully about why you think instantiating a context would ever be slow, i have never found it to be so, it is much more liekly that running queries is slow.

Comment: you aren't using repository pattern eh? do you have a service class, or is your Data Access Logic in the controllers?

Comment: t4 template could be a good route to go here.. do you intend to do this as a release build in the production environment for this logging?  I usually do my diagnostics in Directives "#If Debug", but production environment issues haven't really reared up on me.